# SparkException: Matlab worker did not connect back in time

Tags: matlab, apache-spark

I am using the following code from the Matlab documentation of matlab.compiler.mlspark.RDD class.

```
 %% Connect to Spark
sparkProp = containers.Map({'spark.executor.cores'}, {'1'});
conf = matlab.compiler.mlspark.SparkConf('AppName','myApp', ...
                        'Master','local[1]','SparkProperties',sparkProp);
sc = matlab.compiler.mlspark.SparkContext(conf);

%% flatMap
inRDD = sc.parallelize({'A','B'});
flatRDD = inRDD.flatMap(@(x)({x,1}));
viewRes = flatRDD.collect()

%% Delete Spark Context
delete(sc)
```

When I execute the code, I am able to connect to the Spark using Matlab and the Matlab worker also starts. As soon as the Matlab worker starts I get the following exception and the worker shuts down.

LOGS:

> 17/03/15 21:20:02 INFO MatlabWorkerFactory:  Matlab worker factory
>   create simple worker
>       17/03/15 21:20:02 INFO MatlabWorkerFactory: Launching MATLAB
>       17/03/15 21:20:02 INFO MatlabWorkerFactory: Matlab worker process started
>       17/03/15 21:21:02 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
>       org.apache.spark.SparkException: Matlab worker did not connect back in time

Looks like a configuration issue to me. Having said that, I am very new to both Spark and Matlab, therefore will appreciate any help on it.